# How do I compile google android gingerbread Calendar app from source?

Tags: android, android-calendar

I am trying to compile the google calendar app from source found [here](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_calendar/tree/gingerbread-mr4-release).

The android version is Gingerbread Level 10.

I imported the project on eclipse, but looks like there are multiple references to android source code, which is not compiling, for instance:

```
import dalvik.system.VMRuntime;
import android.provider.Calendar.Events;
```

I've been searching the web, but so far nothing very helpful.
Where could I find a jar that contains all these classes? Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The AOSP apps are not SDK apps. They are designed to be built as part of a full OS build. Instructions for doing that can be found on [the AOSP site](http://source.android.com/source/building.html).

Alternatively, you are welcome to do what others have done (e.g., the original authors of K-9 Mail, derived from the AOSP Email app way back when) and modify the source code of the Calendar app to remove any non-SDK references, possibly at the cost of losing some features.